# WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error

Tags: typescript, next.js, web3js, solana, solana-web3js

When I try to create a PDA I get an error.

```
Error: Unexpected error
    at oi.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:214683)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at s (<anonymous>:1:1456)
```

With all this, the instructions for transferring SOL(SystemProgram.transfer) are completed successfully

Code for creating PDA

```
    const [pda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [wallet.publicKey?.toBuffer()],
        PROGRAM_ID
    )

    const minimumBalance = await connection.connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(128)

    transaction.add(SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: pda,
        lamports: minimumBalance,
        space: 128,
        programId: SystemProgram.programId

    }))

    try {
        const singnature = await wallet.sendTransaction(transaction, connection.connection)
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
```